# Limitation of Gradle’s new variant-aware dependency management when creating a new module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have multiple modules in a project. I try to create a new module (Phone & Tablet Module) within the project. But when the Gradle tries to sync, I get the error:

```
Error:(1, 0) Due to a limitation of Gradle’s new variant-aware dependency management, loading the Android Gradle plugin in different class loaders leads to a build error.
This can occur when the buildscript classpaths that contain the Android Gradle plugin in sub-projects, or included projects in the case of composite builds, are set differently.
To resolve this issue, add the Android Gradle plugin to only the buildscript classpath of the top-level build.gradle file.
In the case of composite builds, also make sure the build script classpaths that contain the Android Gradle plugin are identical across the main and included projects.
If you are using a version of Gradle that has fixed the issue, you can disable this check by setting android.enableBuildScriptClasspathCheck=false in the gradle.properties file.
To learn more about this issue, go to https://d.android.com/r/tools/buildscript-classpath-check.html.
```

Some methods that I tried are:

- Making the buildscript classpaths identical among modules.
- Removing everything from the module's Gradle in order that it syncs.
- Importing a module instead of creating a new one.

Comment: +1 for your question, and Well I'm not really a pro in gradle world.
But I want to know how to solve this kinda problem, for I am also do create android apps. So, if possible I wanted to help solving this problem.
As for my first possible solution, did this
(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0) solve your problem